# SQL query to fetch rows from one table which are not present in other 3 tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 4 tables,

A, B , C , D

A has column Aid,
B has column Aid,
C has column Aid,
D has column Aid

(Aid is common column in all the 4 tables)

now i want to fetch rows from A table which are not present in B or C or D
can anyone please let me know the SQL query for this.

Answer (score 3):

Prepare example data:

```
CREATE TABLE A (aid int);
CREATE TABLE B (aid int);
CREATE TABLE C (aid int);
CREATE TABLE D (aid int);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO A VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO C VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO D VALUES (4);
```

Query:

```
SELECT aid
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.aid=B.aid
LEFT OUTER JOIN C on A.aid=C.aid
LEFT OUTER JOIN D on A.aid=D.aid
WHERE B.aid IS NULL AND C.aid IS NULL AND D.aid IS NULL;
```

The results are `1` and `5`.

Comment: Good solution, but note that it supposes NULL is not a valid value for the Aid attribute.

Comment: @FabianPijcke I used SQLite, where the missing values for the outer join become null. I'm not sure how it works in Oracle.

Comment: Yes, but I mean that if there is a NULL value in A.aid and in B.aid, it will occur in the result, while it should not :-)

Comment: The IS NULL is because tables B C and D have to have no matching entries - so are in table A only. The constraints on aid column are irrelevant. There is no A.aid NULL check http://rextester.com/EZCMI50013

Comment: The OUTER word can be dropped though

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `MINUS` operator:

```
SELECT Aid FROM A
MINUS
SELECT Aid FROM B
MINUS
SELECT Aid FROM C
MINUS
SELECT Aid FROM D
```

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE A ( Aid, Value ) AS
  SELECT 1, '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, '4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '5' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE B ( Aid, BValue ) AS
  SELECT 1, '3' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE C ( Aid, CValue ) AS
  SELECT 4, '7' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE D ( Aid, DValue ) AS
  SELECT NULL, '9' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Aid FROM A
MINUS
SELECT Aid FROM B
MINUS
SELECT Aid FROM C
MINUS
SELECT Aid FROM D
```

**Output**:

```
AID
---
  2
  3
```

**Update to get all columns of `A`**:

This will exclude rows where the `Aid` is equal or when both are `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.Aid = B.Aid OR (A.Aid IS NULL AND B.Aid IS NULL))
AND    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE A.Aid = C.Aid OR (A.Aid IS NULL AND C.Aid IS NULL))
AND    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM D WHERE A.Aid = D.Aid OR (A.Aid IS NULL AND D.Aid IS NULL));
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete in my opinion : It supposes that Aid is the only attribute in A.

Comment: @FabianPijcke It make no such assumption - `SELECT Aid FROM A` will only select the `Aid` column and it does not matter whether table `A` has one or more columns as any others are not being considered by the statement.

Comment: Yes, but the question states "i want to fetch rows from A", and it is not said that table A contains only the column Aid. Adapting your query to retrieve the other columns is not trivial, that's why I believe it is "incomplete".

Comment: @FabianPijcke Updated to address that and `NULL` values (although using `MINUS` will also exclude matching `NULL`s).

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT A.aid 
 FROM   A
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS (select 1 from B where B.aid = A.aid) AND
        NOT EXISTS (select 1 from C where C.aid = A.aid) AND
        NOT EXISTS (select 1 from D where D.aid = A.aid)`

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following query and it will work perfectly.

```
select *  from #A  where  Aid  not in (select Aid   From #B
    UNION
    select Aid   From #C
    Union
    select Aid   From #D)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT IN` operator

```
Select * from A
Where Aid not in (
  Select Aid from B
  Union all
  Select Aid from C
  Union all
  Select Aid from D
)
```

---

> ert that.. If aid is null in table A, but B,C & D don't have null,
>   null won't be returned. Left join is superior in that case... – JGFMK
>   43 mins ago

If table A contains NULL in `aid` column, then left join query will always return that row regardless of there will go NULL in other tables or not. Please examine this simple test case http://rextester.com/ESZWH45744

Comment: use UNION over UNION ALL - that way you'll get distinct results so in theory selection should run faster.

Comment: This will not return any rows if `Aid` is `NULL` in any of tables `B`, `C` or `D`.

Comment: invert that.. If aid is null in table A, but B,C & D don't have null, null won't be returned. Left join is superior in that case...

Comment: @JGFMK I have updated my answer with an example regarding null values and left join, please check it.